# LibreOffice --convert-to pdf

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

After upgrade LibreOffice to version: LibreOffice 5.2.5.1 20m0(Build:1), i have next error. After converting xlsx file to pdf with command

```
soffice --headless --convert-to pdf:calc_pdf_Export test.xlsx
```

Generated PDF file not contain any calculated values, why?? Version LibreOffice 5.1.6.2 10m0(Build:2) works fine. In original xlsx file all formulas calculated fine.

UPDATE:
I'am try change (in my test machine) Tools->Options->LibreOffice Calc->Formula->Recalculation on file load to "Always" and then run convert, works fine, but if selected "Newer/Ask User", formulas not calculated in pdf. How i can change this values without GUI on server? ..